# Display a specific area on the Google Maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Can you please tell if there is a way using the Google Maps API for Android to display only a specific country / city instead of the whole map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/views#restrict-panning

That will restrict the camera to a region

You can use:

```
private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
// Create a LatLngBounds that includes Australia.
private LatLngBounds YOUR_CITY_OR_COUNTRY = new LatLngBounds(
new LatLng(-23, -66), new LatLng(-43, -68));

// Set the camera to the greatest possible zoom level that includes the
// bounds
mGoogleMap.setLatLngBoundsForCameraTarget(YOUR_CITY_OR_COUNTRY);
```