# How to set Android Google Maps to show whole (part) world map once?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin, android-mapview, android-tv

i'm trying to show one whole-world map on android TV (API 29)
and finally with help of `app:liteMode="true"` was able to see the whole map [my tv look (img)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H6UUf.png)

1. could you please help me to set it up so that only green rectangle area (or a bit more without repeat) would be visible?
2. is it possible to remove buttons in red area? reason is the mode `app:liteMode="true"`

***MainActivity.kt***

```
import android.app.Activity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

class MainActivity : Activity() {
    private lateinit var mMap: GoogleMap
    private val center = LatLng(.0, .0)
    private val mine = LatLngBounds(
        LatLng(-30.0,150.0), LatLng(30.0, -150.0)
    )
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        with(mapView) {
            // Initialise the MapView
            onCreate(null)
            // Set the map ready callback to receive the GoogleMap object
            getMapAsync{
                MapsInitializer.initialize(applicationContext)
                setMapLocation(it)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setMapLocation(map : GoogleMap) {
        with(map) {
            moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(center, 1f))
            addMarker(MarkerOptions().position(center))
            mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL
            setOnMapClickListener {
                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Clicked on map", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        mapView.onResume()
    }

    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        mapView.onPause()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        mapView.onDestroy()
    }

    override fun onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory()
        mapView.onLowMemory()
    }
}
```

***activity_main.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/mapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="460dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:liteMode="true" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this out for remove red area buttons:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

    // Do other staff
}
```

also, check this answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/46059720/8399393

I hope to be useful :)

Comment: thank you @hamidkeyhani ! btns were removed, but positioning doesn't work. I already saw that solution. e.g 
    `private val pointFrom = LatLng(-65.0, -180.0) // green
    private val pointTo = LatLng(80.0, 179.0) //blue
    private val mine = LatLngBounds(pointFrom, pointTo)
    moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(mine.center, 1f))`
does https://ibb.co/kHvPpCz